# Simpliest way to generate a 1D gaussian kernel

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm wondering what would be the easiest way to generate a 1D gaussian kernel in python given the filter length. I think that the idea is to evaluate the normal distribution for the values of the vector [-filter-length,...,filter_length], is it correct?

So far, I've done this, but I don't know why it is not correct:

```
result = np.zeros( filter_length )

mid = filter_length/2
result=[(1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*(1/(numpy.exp((i**2)/(2*sigma**2)))) for i in range(-mid,mid+1)]  

return result
```

where `sigma` is the standard deviation, which is a parameter. `filter-length` is also a parameter.

It's incorrect because I get, for example, for length=3 and **sigma=math.sqrt(1.0/2/math.log(2))**

[0.23485931967491286, 0.46971863934982572, 0.23485931967491286]

And it should be:

[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]

So, is there any problem of rounding? I don't know what is going on...

**Edit** I think that I should truncate somehow

**Problem Solved** The problem was that I wasn't normalizing. I had to divide the vector by the sum of all its components.

Comment: what value is sigma for the results you give?

Comment: for sigma=1 i think the values should be [0.24,0.40,0.24].  i am unsure why you expect [0.25,0.5,0.25].

Comment: no, it's for sigma=math.sqrt(1.0/2/math.log(2))

Comment: I have added what I think is the correct sigma to my answer, at least with the Gaussian formula you use. Why did you choose sigma=math.sqrt(1.0/2/math.log(2))?

Comment: [0.25, 0.5, 0.25] is a triangular kernel, not a Gaussian. You cannot make a Gaussian kernel this short, it will never share the good properties of the Gaussian kernel. You need more samples. See here for details: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695/

Answer (score 5):

I am not very firm with numpy syntax, but if you convolve a kernel with a dirac impulse, you get the same kernel as output.

So you could simply use the inbuild [scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d) function, and use this array as input: [ 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 1, 0, ...0, 0, 0]

The output should be a gaussian kernel, with a value of 1 at its peak. (replace 1 with the maximum you want in your desired kernel)

So in essence, you will get the Gaussian kernel that gaussian_filter1d function uses internally as the output. This should be the simplest and least error-prone way to generate a Gaussian kernel, and you can use the same approach to generate a 2d kernel, with the respective scipy 2d function. Of course if the goal is to do it from scratch, then this approach is only good as a reference

*In regards to your equation:*
to get [..., 0.5, ...] as the output with your formula, you need to solve
`(1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) = 0.5`
so the correct sigma should be
`sigma = math.sqrt(2*1/np.pi)`

Comment: reading those docs, you'd want `mode='constant'` and also it's not clear to me whether the amplitude will be 1, or whether the filter has an integrated value of 1.  so you might need to divide by `max(...)`.

Comment: what do you mean that you get the same kernel?

Comment: Yes, you get the same kernel as output that the gaussian_filter1d function uses internally. I am pretty sure that this is the simplest way to generate a 1D Gaussian kernel. Of course, if you want to generate the kernel from scratch as an exercise, you will need a different approach. But you could at least use this method as a reference to compare to your output

Answer (score 0):

For those that like to have a fully working copy/paste code example:

```
import numpy as np

filter_length = 3
sigma=math.sqrt(1.0/2/math.log(2))
result = np.zeros( filter_length )

mid = int(filter_length/2)
result=[(1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*(1/(np.exp((i**2)/(2*sigma**2)))) for i in range(-mid,mid+1)]  
sumresult = np.sum(result)
print(result/sumresult)
```

[0.25 0.5  0.25]

Comment: If you’re going to normalize, you can leave the `1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))` computation out. It’s no longer doing anything.